# Can't install mongoose

Tags: mongoose, installation, port-number

I got error message when installing mongoose stating error starting server on port 8080: failed to open listener. Oracle 11g express edition in running on the port. I want Oracle should run on the same port. Is there any way to install mongoose by changing it's port?

Comment: Do you mean mongoose, the ORM for momgodb?

Comment: My understanding was wrong initially . Got the output as required